# How to get thumbnails for scaling?

Tags: android, thumbnails

As i understand there is a thumbnail MINI_KIND: 512 x 384
How do i get the list of URI of this thumbnails, as it is easier to resize image from 512px thumbnails than from 1920px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve `MINI_KIND` thumbnails this way, `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null)` "cr" is a ContentResolver type , that particular function returns a bitmap, but you can get URI's from the `ContentResolver`

There are also `MICRO_KIND` thumbnails

That should help direct your search